# An extension of a corollary to Fuglede's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Fuglede's theorem states that if $T,N\in B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$ and  $N$ is normal and $TN = NT$, then $TN^* = N^*T$. A corollary to this theorem is that if $M,N \in B(H)$ are normal and similar, then they are in fact unitarily equivalent. [See Wiki.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuglede's_theorem)

My question is:

> If $M\in B(H_1)$ and $N\in B(H_2)$ ($H_1$ not necessarily the same as $H_2$ but both separable and infinite dimensional, e.g. weighted $L^2$ spaces) are normal and similar ($M = S^{-1}NS$ for some bounded invertible operator $S$ with bounded inverse), are they still unitarily equivalent?

The obvious thing to do I guess is since they're separable and infinite dimensional, they're isometrically isomorphic to each other so there is an isometric isomorphism $T:H_1\to H_2$. After playing with some diagrams, it doesn't seem obvious to me how to construct a similarity transformation with $T$ and $S$. I feel like I'm chasing my tail a bit but maybe it's really obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $H_1$ and $H_2$ have the same dimension, there exists a unitary $W:H_1\to H_2$. Then $M$ and $WNW^*$ are both normal and in $B(H_1)$. Moreover, 
$$
M=S^{-1}NS=(WS)^{-1}WNW^*(WS),
$$
so they are similar. By the Corollary you quoted, there exists a unitary $V$ with 
$$
M=VWNW^*V^*.
$$
So $M$ and $N$ are unitarily equivalent.

Comment: I was thinking of using a clever form of one but didn't think to show that $M$ and $WNW^*$ are similar to invoke the corollary. That's really clever!